# How to make git understand Mac (CR) line endings

Tags: git, macos, cross-platform, compatibility, line-endings

For some reasons one of my files contains old style Mac line endings (after editing on OSX). These are "CR" (carriage return) characters and show up as ^M in `git diff`.

Git does not understand that they are line ending codes (really how hard can it be?) and interprets the whole file as a single line.

I know that I can convert the files to LF or CRLF endings and then commit them back, however since git automatically converts my Windows (CRLF) line endings to LF, I was hoping that it would take care of CR line endings as well.

Is there a way to make git interpret CR as a line ending?

Comment: Sublime is my main text editor and I have discovered that there is an option to replace line endings under `View->Line Endings` (why the hell is it under "View"?) so I guess I'll turn off `autocrlf` in git and manage line endings myself, unless someone answers my question with a solution to make git deal with all line endings, not just Unix and Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Create a filter driver plus `.gitattributes`: create a *smudge filter* that runs `tr '\n' '\r'` and a *clean filter* that runs `tr '\r' '\n'`, and mark the file(s) in question as using this filter.  Store the file inside Git using LF-only line endings.  (The filter driver is defined in a `.git/config` or `$HOME/.gitconfig` file and the names or name-patterns for the files go in `.gitattributes`.)

#### Long

As you have seen, Git strongly prefers newline-terminated lines.  (It can work with newline-separated lines, where the last line is missing the terminator, but this means that adding a line results in a change to the previous final line, since it now has a newline terminator while the new final line is missing the newline terminator.)  This does not matter for the individual snapshots, but does matter for producing useful diffs.

Modern MacOS uses newlines, like everyone else.  Only ancient backwards-compatible formats have CR-only line endings.  See, e.g., [this SuperUser Stack Exchange web site posting](https://superuser.com/q/439440/941003).

Git does not have a *built in* filter for converting to or from such line endings.  Git *does*, however, have a *general purpose mechanism* for making alterations in work-tree files.

Remember that when Git stores any file in a snapshot, the file is represented by what Git calls a *blob object*, which is stored internally in a special, compressed (sometimes highly compressed), Git-only form.  This form is not useful to anything *but* Git, so when you get the files in a useful form—via `git checkout`, for instance—Git expands them into their usual form for your computer.  Meanwhile, any time you take a normal file like this and convert it to Git-only form, Git compresses the file down to its Git-only form.  That happens whenever you copy a file back into Git's *index* using `git add`.

The index copy of each file exists while you have the work-tree in place, just like the committed copy.  The index copy is in the same Git-only format.  The key difference here is that the committed copy *can't* be changed, but the index copy *can* be changed.  Running `git commit` takes a snapshot of whatever is in the index *right at that point*, and makes that the new snapshot for the new commit.  Hence the index acts as *what will go into the next commit*.  Using `git checkout`, you copy some existing commit *into* the index, and have Git expand it into the work-tree; then using `git add`, you selectively replace particular index copies with compressed versions of the work-tree files that you have changed.

This copying, to or from index and work-tree, is the ideal point at which to do Windows-style LF-to-CRLF conversions, or vice versa, so this is where Git does it.  If you have some *other* conversion to perform, not directly built in to Git, this is where you tell Git to do it.

#### Smudge and clean filters

A *smudge filter* is one that Git applies when converting a file from compressed index copy to work-tree copy.  Here, if you've chosen to have newline characters replaced with CRLF Windows-style line enders-or-separators, Git has an internal converter that will do that: `eol=crlf`.  A *clean filter* is one that Git applies when converting a file from uncompressed work-tree copy to compressed index copy; here again, `eol=crlf` directs Git to do the backwards conversion.

If you want to replace newlines with CR-only, you must invent your own converters.  Let's say you call the overall process `convert-cr`:

```
*.csv   filter=convert-cr
```

(instead of `*.csv eol=crlf`).  This line goes into `.gitattributes` (which is a commit-able file, and you should commit it).

Now you must define the `convert-cr` filter.  This goes in a Git configuration file, and here we find a minor flaw: the configuration file is not commit-able.  This is a security issue: Git will run arbitrary commands here, and if I could commit this file and you clone it, you'll run the commands *I* specify, without getting a chance to vet them first.  So you must put this into your `.git/config` yourself, or into your global configuration (`git config --global --edit` for instance):

```
[filter "convert-cr"]
    clean = tr '\r' '\n'
    smudge = tr '\n' '\r'
```

Now whenever Git converts *from* Git-only format, it will translate the newlines to CRs, and whenever Git converts *to* Git-only format, it will translate the CRs to newlines.

#### This does not help with existing stored files

Any existing snapshots that you have today that have `\r` inside them, are stored that way forever.  Git will never change any existing stored file!  Stored data are precious and inviolate.  There is nothing you can do about this.  Well, there is *almost* nothing: you can throw out those commits entirely, making new and improved commits that you use instead.  But that's quite painful: every commit remembers its *parent* commits, so if you replace an early commit in your repository, you must replace *every* child, grandchild, and so on, so that they all remember this new sequence of commits.  (`git filter-branch` does this job.)

You can, however, instruct Git about how to *diff* particular files in existing commits, also using `.gitattributes` and *diff drivers*.  There are multiple ways to do this, but the simplest is to define a *textconv* attribute, that turns a "binary" file—such as a file whose stored version might have CR-only characters—into a text (line-oriented, i.e., newline-based) file.  The textconv filter to use here is precisely the same as the smudge filter.

For further details, see [the gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html).

Comment: I'm not sure how CR line endings were introduced in my code - I yet have to investigate this.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and easy to understand answer. When I first encountered issues with line endings, I just wanted to commit files with whichever line ending and `git` to handle the different line endings without changing the files. Now I understand how it could create issues. For example if the same source file existed in different branches but with different line endings, then git would have to treat the files as identical despite different file sizes. It makes more sense to just normalize line endings. Your solution is probably the closest that I would get to my utopia.

Comment: It's nice that they allow running arbitrary commands like this, but it would be nicer to be able to just commit a config file that says the end of line pattern is `\r\n?|\n`... I guess they wanted to avoid using any patterns in line splitting though.

Comment: @Andy: regular expressions are not useful here—at least not directly–as the goal is to do some kind of transformation. A regexp would be useful elsewhere, such as when doing `git merge` (which must read and combine two separate diffs), except that the actual difference engine has newline hardcoded inside it for performance reasons.

Comment: Is there any possibility to get this filter working on Windows? 

As I have understood it, tr is not possible in Windows and its lacking a counterpart.

Comment: @T-Dog18: you can do any of these on Windows but you might need to install extra software (e.g., the Cygwin tools). I don't use Windows and my experience is terribly out of date at this point (I used Cygwin around 2008, I think).

Answer (score 2):

Since the accepted answer, a new way to do this has been introduced.

You can teach `git diff` and `git log` to run the file through a special command before creating the diff. This is a one-way process, which is just used for generating diffs, and doesn't affect how the files are stored on disk or in your repository.

Create a new diff driver called "cr", which runs the file through `tr` before calculating the diff. In your `.git/config`:

```
[diff "cr"]
    textconv = tr '\\r' '\\n' <
```

Alternatively:

```
git config diff.cr.textconv "tr '\r' '\n' <"
```

Then tell git to use it using your `.gitattributes` (e.g. for all .csv files):

```
*.csv diff=cr
```

Note that this *only* affects diffs. It won't help you with merging!

Comment: It's useful to highlight this, but I will note that I did include it in my answer (at the end). You may need to put some attributes into `.git/info/attributes` so as to override any `.gitattributes` settings in old commits.